# has_key in Nested Dictionary

Tags: python-2.7

I need help in a python problem. Lets suppose there are three Dictionaries.

```
{"key":{"s":"1","z":"2"}}

{"b":{"s":"1","key":"2"}}

{"a":{"s":"1","z":"2", "x":{"key":"2"}}}
```

I want has_key("key") to return true for all of the above Dictionaries.

Comment: Do you want arbitrary depth, or just 3?

Comment: No it can be more than 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define your own version of has_key:

```
def myhaskey(d): return d.has_key('key') or any(myhaskey(dd) for dd in d.values() if isinstance(dd, dict))
```

The above checks for a key of `"key"` in dictionary `d` or in any dictionary contained in `d` at any depth.

Comment: @Ahmad.Masood It will work at all depths.  It inspects the dictionary _recursively_.